# You may need to run helm dependency build to fetch missing dependencies: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory

Tags: hashicorp-vault, argocd, argocd-notification

my dependency is located in a private Artifactory instance. For authentication, I added it as a Helm repository in ArgoCD. However, when using the plugin, the dependency is not pulled, whereas it is pulled when the plugin is not used.

error with helm repo update :
Unable to create application: application spec for abj is invalid: InvalidSpecError: Unable to generate manifests in h1: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Manifest generation error (cached): plugin sidecar failed. error generating manifests in cmp: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error generating manifests: sh -c helm repo update helm dependency build failed exit status 1: Error: no repositories found. You must add one before updating

error without helm repo update in the configmap
Unable to create application: application spec for abj is invalid: InvalidSpecError: Unable to generate manifests in h1: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Manifest generation error (cached): plugin sidecar failed. error generating manifests in cmp: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error generating manifests: sh -c helm repo update helm dependency build failed exit status 1: Error: no repositories found. You must add one before updating

thank you

Note: this command is run before any Helm templating is done, therefore the logic is to check
if this looks like a Helm chart
discover:

find:

command:

```
- sh

- "-c"

- "find . -name 'Chart.yaml' && find . -name 'values.yaml'"
```

init:

command:

```
- sh

- "-c"

- "helm repo update"

- "helm dependency build"
```

generate:

## **IMPORTANT**: passing `${ARGOCD_ENV_helm_args}` effectively allows users to run arbitrary code in the Argo CD

## repo-server (or, if using a sidecar, in the plugin sidecar). Only use this when the users are completely trusted. If

## possible, determine which Helm arguments are needed by your users and explicitly pass only those arguments.

command:

- sh
- "-c"
- |

  helm template $ARGOCD_APP_NAME -n $ARGOCD_APP_NAMESPACE ${ARGOCD_ENV_HELM_ARGS} . |

  argocd-vault-plugin generate -
  lockRepo: false